# How to remove extra lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival

I'm trying to create a graph of survival over time at a number of different sites.

I have a fairly simple dataframe as below

[image]

I have used the following code to make the plot:

```
my_df <- data.frame(x = Survival$time, y = Survival$`% survival`, group = Survival$Site)

ggplot(my_df, aes(x = Survival$time, y = Survival$`% survival`,colour=as.factor("Site"))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = group, group=1)) +# Points and color by group
  geom_path(aes(colour=group, group=1), na.value="blank")+
  scale_color_discrete("Site", na.value=NA) +# Change legend title
  xlab("Time in Months") +              # X-axis label
  ylab("Percent Survival")  +             # Y-axis label
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", # Changes the default theme
                                 size = 0.24))
```

However for some reason there seems to be an extra green line and an extra grey line

[image]

Just wondering why this may be and what would be the best way to fix this issue

Comment: 1) remove `Survival$` from the `aes` call; 2) `"Site"` is not a column in your data, it should be `as.factor(group)`. 3) after defining the colour aes, do not include it again, the calls `geom_path()` and `geom_point()` should have nothing between the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a situation where all of the suggestions of @Rui Barradas in the comments are implemented and some other tweaks:

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df %>% 
  transmute(time = parse_number(X),
            survival = y, group = group) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = survival, colour=factor(group), group=group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(size = 1) +
  scale_color_discrete("group", na.value=NA) +# Change legend title
  labs(title = "Survival", x = "Time in Months", y = "Percent Survival")  +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.24),
        aspect.ratio=4/5)
```

[image]

data:

```
structure(list(X = c("0 Months", "2 Months", "4 Months", "6 Months", 
"0 Months", "2 Months", "4 Months", "6 Months", "0 Months", "2 Months", 
"4 Months", "6 Months", "0 Months", "2 Months", "4 Months", "6 Months"
), y = c(100, 56.45161, 35.48387, 24.19355, 100, 80.76923, 61.53846, 
34.61538, 100, 53.06122, 44.89796, 24.4898, 100, 60, 48.57143, 
40), group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```